# Record form submit (but not post with) jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

Is there a way to record a successful client-side form submit event with jQuery without making a request or posting data for testing? Or, put another way, is there a way to separate the submit event from the post request? For example, say I've got:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
            "url", 
            $(this).serialize(), 
            function(data){
                console.log("Form success")
            }
        );
    });
 });
```

How could this be re-writtern to record the form submit but not send data? I can set the form submit button to onclick="trackClickFunction()" but that just confirms the button was clicked. Can ajax() accomplish this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
var savedVars;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".myForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        savedVars = $(this).serialize();
    });
});
```

THen you'll have access to the serialized values globally in `savedVars`